# how to use custom pagination inside antd table react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, antd

I'm using antd table React Js for my work. Right now, I got a requirement to change the behaviour of pagination inside antd table. I will need to control the previous and next button on pagination component. For this reason I need to make a custom pagination for antd table. The requirements are:

- Data inside table will be retrieved 50 records/API call.
- Data inside table will be displayed 10 records/page.
- `next` button on pagination will be enabled if there are remaining data in the system but not being retrieved yet, and will be disabled otherwise.
  E.g. there are 100 records in system. First API call will get 50 latest records (no 100 - 50) and will be rendered into the table. Since one page will display 10 records, it will be in 5 pages. After user arrived in page 5, the `next` button will be available because there are remaining 50 records in the system. If user click the `next`, API will be called for the second time and data inside the table will appended and total page will be 10 because, all of data has been retrieved. `next` button will disabled after the second API call and user only able to go to page 10 for the last page.

I believe that antd pagination doesn't support of controlling `next` and `prev` button as I cannot find the props to control the state of the `next` and `prev` button in the documentation (https://ant.design/components/pagination/#API). For the table documentation, I also don't find props to change the pagination component. (https://ant.design/components/table/#API)

 
My question is, how do I embedded my custom pagination component to antd table ? To be noted that, my table also has filter and sorting function. So, I don't want to change the behaviour of those function. Example code and explanation would be really great, thank you.

Comment: `pageSize` and `current` are the pagination props you should look into. However, you'll also need to ensure the API response returns a "next" field so that you know there are more records that can be fetched. That being said, I'm curious how you have your filter and sorting functions implemented because if you're only fetching a portion of the records, your filter and sort may be applied to a portion of the entire data... unless you're passing these filters/sorters as parameters to the API.

Comment: I'm using the antd table filter and sorting function, so to answer your question yes, it will not applied to all data. May I know how these two props (pageSize and current) can be used to manipulate the behaviour of pagination ?

Comment: `pageSize` and `current` will control the paginator's page size (how many records to show per page) and current page (which page you're on). You should also look into the `onChange` prop since it observes for changes in either the page size or page number. You'll need to write your own `onChange` handler to determine when to make another API fetch call, using the state variables you passed into `pageSize` and `current`. (Hint: It will require the use of the remainder operator, `%`)

Comment: I think I got the idea, thank you very much for your help! This way no need to make the custom pagination.